# Area measurement with out geodesic in openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, area

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Measure example</title>
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/jquery1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
<!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="ol.js"></script>

<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tooltip-measure {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tooltip-static {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.tooltip-measure:before,
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  left: 50%;
}
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top-color: #ffcc33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
    <select id="type">
      <option value="length">Length</option>
      <option value="area">Area</option>
    </select>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="geodesic"/>use geodesic measures</label>
</form>

</div>
<script>
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
 title: 'India',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://172.31.4.37/geoserver/ndem50k/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'ndem50k:apstateadmin50nrsc2014'}
            })
 // source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});


/**
 * Currently drawn feature.
 * @type {ol.Feature}
 */
var sketch;


/**
 * The help tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var helpTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the help messages.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var helpTooltip;


/**
 * The measure tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var measureTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the measurement.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var measureTooltip;


/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';


/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';


/**
 * Handle pointer move.
 * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt
 */
var pointerMoveHandler = function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  /** @type {string} */
  var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
  /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
  var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

  if (sketch) {
    var output;
    var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
      output = formatArea(/** @type {ol.geom.Polygon} */ (geom));
      helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
      tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
      output = formatLength( /** @type {ol.geom.LineString} */ (geom));
      helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
      tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
    }
    measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
    measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
  }

  helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
  helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
};


var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 15
  })
});

map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
var geodesicCheckbox = document.getElementById('geodesic');

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {
  var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (type),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);

  createMeasureTooltip();
  createHelpTooltip();

  draw.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {
        // set sketch
        sketch = evt.feature;
      }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        // unset sketch
        sketch = null;
        // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
      }, this);
}


/**
 * Creates a new help tooltip
 */
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}


/**
 * Creates a new measure tooltip
 */
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}


/**
 * Let user change the geometry type.
 * @param {Event} e Change event.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function(e) {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  addInteraction();
};


/**
 * format length output
 * @param {ol.geom.LineString} line
 * @return {string}
 */
var formatLength = function(line) {
  var length;
  if (geodesicCheckbox.checked) {
    var coordinates = line.getCoordinates();
    length = 0;
    var sourceProj = map.getView().getProjection();
    for (var i = 0, ii = coordinates.length - 1; i < ii; ++i) {
      var c1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i], sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');
      var c2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i + 1], sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');
      length += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2);
    }
  } else {
    length = Math.round(line.getLength() * 100) / 100;
  }
  var output;
  if (length > 100) {
    output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
};


/**
 * format length output
 * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon
 * @return {string}
 */
var formatArea = function(polygon) {
  var area;
  if (geodesicCheckbox.checked) {
    var sourceProj = map.getView().getProjection();
    var geom = /** @type {ol.geom.Polygon} */(polygon.clone().transform(
        sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326'));
    var coordinates = geom.getLinearRing(0).getCoordinates();
    area = Math.abs(wgs84Sphere.geodesicArea(coordinates));
  } else {
    area = polygon.getArea();
  }
  var output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
  }
  return output;
};

addInteraction();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to perform only area measurement that to by using button click I have gone through it and changed my code relevant to requirement can any one suggest where I am getting problem when I am removing the geodesic radio button option its not showing the map part why?

---

Changed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Measure example</title>
<script src="lib/jquery1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="ol.js"></script>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tooltip-measure {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tooltip-static {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.tooltip-measure:before,
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  left: 50%;
}
.tooltip-static:before {
  border-top-color: #ffcc33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<form class="form-inline">
        <button  id="barea" onclick=formatearea();><img src="img/area.png"></button>

        </form>

</div>
<script>
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
 title: 'India',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://172.31.4.37/geoserver/ndem50k/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'ndem50k:apstateadmin50nrsc2014'}
            })

});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});

var sketch;var helpTooltipElement;var helpTooltip;var measureTooltipElement;var measureTooltip;
var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';
var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';
var pointerMoveHandler = function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
  var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
  if (sketch) {
    var output;
    var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
      output = formatArea((geom));
      helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
      tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {

    }
    measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
    measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
  }

  helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
  helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
};

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 15
  })
});

map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);
var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
var geodesicCheckbox = document.getElementById('geodesic');

//var but = document.getElementById('type');///////////////////
var draw; 
function addInteraction() {
  var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area'? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type:(type),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);

  createMeasureTooltip();
  createHelpTooltip();

  draw.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {
        sketch = evt.feature;
      }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        sketch = null;
         measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
      }, this);
}

function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}

function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}

typeSelect.onchange = function(e) {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  addInteraction();
};

var formatArea = function(polygon) {
  var area;
 if (geodesicCheckbox.checked) {

  } else {
    area = polygon.getArea();
  }
  var output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
  }
  return output;
};
addInteraction();

</script>
</body>
</html>

    enter code here
```

Comment: How to chage the functionality into button ? please check the link http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/measure.html

Comment: this functionality i want to change into area button onclick measure the area and like line button it has to measure the line length

Answer (score 1):

You removed the checkbox for geodesic measure and the list for the type of geometry from your HTML but they are still used in your JS like here for example :

```
 var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
 var geodesicCheckbox = document.getElementById('geodesic');
```

you'll need to take off all these lines and every call to these 2 variables from your JS code.